# The volume of the solid, generated by revolving about $y = 2$ the region bounded by $y^2\leq 2x, x \leq 8$ and $y \geq 2$, is

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

The volume of the solid, generated by revolving about $y = 2$ the region bounded by $y^2\leq 2x, x \leq 8$ and $y \geq 2$, is

(A) $2\sqrt2\pi$ (B) $28\pi /3$ (C) $84\pi$ (D) none of these.

My Steps:

Total Volume of solid formed by the revolution of the area

$\begin{align} A & =\displaystyle\int\int\limits_A 2\pi y\;dy\;dx\\
& = \displaystyle\int\limits_{x=2}^{x=8}\int\limits_{y=2}^{y=\sqrt{2x}} 2\pi y\;dy\;dx \\
& = \displaystyle\int\limits_{x=2}^{x=8} 2\pi \frac{y^2}{2}|_{y=2}^{y=\sqrt{2x}}\;dx \\
& = \displaystyle\int\limits_{x=2}^{x=8} \pi y^2|_{y=2}^{y=\sqrt{2x}}\;dx \\
& = \displaystyle\int\limits_{x=2}^{x=8} \pi (2x-4) \;dx \\
& = 2\pi \frac{x^2}{2}|_{x=2}^{x=8}-4\pi x|_{x=2}^{x=8} \;dx \\
& = 36\pi
\end{align}$

Is this correct ? or did I make some mistake here ? Please help me confirm my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup should be a single integral (not a double one):

$$\pi\int_2^8 (\sqrt{2x}-2)^2 dx$$

See the following picture:

[image]

$A,B,C$ enclosed the region you want to rotate. Then we find the volume of the cone-shaped object. This has nothing to do with dividing by $2$.

Comment: why not a double one ?

Comment: Your double integral only give you the volume between $xy$-plane and the surface $z=2\pi y$. It is not a solid of revolution. You need to use $\pi r^2$ to represent the cross-sectional area.

Comment: shouldn't we devide $$\pi\int_2^8 (\sqrt{2x}-2)^2 dx$$ by 2 ? since $y \ge $2 has been mentioned ?

Comment: @saudade: $y\geq 2$ is to enclose a region. When it is revolved around an axis, it becomes a cone-shaped solid. You want to find the volume of this whole solid. So no dividing by $2$.

Comment: would you please explain a little explicitly, maybe with a diagram ? I'm not understanding !

Comment: @saudade: See the picture in my edit. Hope it helps.